# How Can I filter a Column A/Q to certain condition in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi

I want to filter out a column, or just create another column with the following conditions, I am not able to do this in Power Bi However I can do this in Tableaue quite easly, actually I have created 2 parameters but I am not sure How can I use them to filter out a column or jus create another column with the filtered values. The condition that I want to use:-

[Aggregation] >= [Start Date Parameter] AND [Aggregation] <= [End Date Parameter]

Please guide me How can I do this in real time??

Comment: Power BI doesn't do parameters quite the same way as Tableau. You can probably use a date slicer to achieve the same result though.

Comment: Actually I achieved that filter by adding the column and applying advanced filtering on the column it was quite easy.

Comment: Can you tell me How can I add index rows on a direct query in powerbi??